# Create a new array of object based on the ids of the objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to transform an array of object into new array based on the parent_id's in the list. In the below given input we have a parent_id which tells use parent of the given object.

**Input**:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Item 2",
    "parent_id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Item 3",
    "parent_id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Item 4",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Item 5",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "title": "Item 6",
    "parent_id": 5
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "title": "Item 7",
    "parent_id": 6
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "title": "Item 8",
    "parent_id": 6
  }
]
```

**Desired Output**:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Item 1",
    "parent_id": null,
    "child": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Item 2",
        "parent_id": 1,
        "child": [{
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Item 3",
            "parent_id": 2
        }]
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Item 4",
    "parent_id": null
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "Item 5",
    "parent_id": null,
    "child": [{
        "id": 6,
        "title": "Item 6",
        "parent_id": 5,
        "child": [{
            "id": 7,
            "title": "Item 7",
            "parent_id": 6
        }, {
            "id": 8,
            "title": "Item 8",
            "parent_id": 6
        }]
    }]
  }
]
```

In the desired output I have created a nested array of object where each object will hold its children.
Can someone please suggest how we can do this in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a loop and build a tree with the help of an object.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, title: "Item 1", parent_id: null }, { id: 2, title: "Item 2", parent_id: 1 }, { id: 3, title: "Item 3", parent_id: 2 }, { id: 4, title: "Item 4", parent_id: null }, { id: 5, title: "Item 5", parent_id: null }, { id: 6, title: "Item 6", parent_id: 5 }, { id: 7, title: "Item 7", parent_id: 6 }, { id: 8, title: "Item 8", parent_id: 6 }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var t = {};
        data.forEach(o => {
            Object.assign(t[o.id] = t[o.id] || {}, o);
            t[o.parent_id] = t[o.parent_id] || {};
            t[o.parent_id].children = t[o.parent_id].children || [];
            t[o.parent_id].children.push(t[o.id]);
        });
        return t[root].children;
    }(data, null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```